# Check iOS capture resolution of camera

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, avcapturesession

I am using OpenGL on iOS 7 to render the front camera video capture to a `UIView`
on the iPhone display ( same iphone 5). I am using  `AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480`
and passing this to `AVCaptureSession` method

```
[captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];
```

However the rendered video seems to be a lower resolution than set as above,
it seems to be `AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288`. In fact whatever constant I pass
from these makes no difference the resolution is the same

```
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame1280x720;
NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetInputPriority;
```

How can I check what resolution the camera is actually capturing at?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the dimensions of the buffer being captured, as follows (for `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` you need to capture a still image, of course, rather than reading the video frame...):

```
- (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
       didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
              fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
  {
    CVPixelBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // "width" and "height" now hold your dimensions...

  }
```